# Give user A full access to user B and vice versa

Tags: permissions, users

I have two users. Each user has a project.

### Problem:

I need to work on both projects simultaneously, but I always have to login at the other user to make changes, because otherwise I have no permissions.

I have split the project to two users, because I need another set of aliases for both users. Both projects are running with different PHP versions and the aliases need to reference the right one. The aliases are for project specific CLI commands.

### Question:

Is there a way to give user A the full access to user B and vice versa?

Comment: Best method: do not do it. Use git, and give both the permission to push to the server version. Else: what about creating the code in common group (e.g. force an *activate* script so user get into the group and umask is correctly set).

Comment: Git makes no sense in this context. Im trying to develope and sometimes I need to transfer code (e.g. extensions) from one project to the other

Comment: you can do with git. It is most that git gives you documentation, and split the coding with the deployment. I assume that user A and user B are just used for deployment and so you have two user to separate programs in case of problems (and hacks). If you put all together, you do not need two users. We all start as your question, but when you discover how to do properly you never look back.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the problem. They are two separate repositories from two different companies. They DONT share the same repository so git is not helping me at all.

Comment: I understand the problem, and I find nothing special. For deployments (especially if we are doing free-software) we have own git repositories with own configurations with several modules (so other repositories, e.g. upstream, and theme customization). But also with a simple case, you are the user, so you should have repositories on same user (so it doesn't matter much). Coding is always done with programmer user. What you are looking is contrary of unix principles, so you may get surprises. (e.g. just ser umask and same main group, or set users with exactly the same UID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to give user A the full access to user B and vice versa?

If you are really both User A and User B (i.e. both accounts can completely trust the other) you could use `sudo` to switch between them. If you put your aliases and other definitions into your login/startup scripts `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` you can even get them run automatically when you switch.

```
# as User A
sudo -su userb    # Or sudo -iu userb

# as User B
sudo -su usera    # Or sudo -iu usera
```

You can set this up so that neither User A nor User B has root permissions, but only sufficient permissions to switch to the other account.

1. Open a root shell (`sudo -s`). Do not close it until you have changed the configuration and *you know* that `sudo` continues to give you root access.
2. Use `visudo` (or `EDITOR=nano visudo` if you don't like `vi`) and add a line near the bottom of the file,

   ```
   usera   ALL=(userb) NOPASSWD: ALL
   userb   ALL=(usera) NOPASSWD: ALL
   ```
3. Test that you can `sudo` from `usera` to `userb` and back again.
4. Test that you can still get root access in the manner you used to achieve step 1.

---

In a comment you note that [you already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727855/give-user-a-full-access-to-user-b-and-vice-versa/727859?noredirect=1#comment1379982_727859) do something like this but want to be able to use either user account and write into the other user's directory tree directly.

Generally I wouldn't recommend this at all, particularly if you've got different configurations for each user's development environment. And especially because it seems they may be [different customers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727855/give-user-a-full-access-to-user-b-and-vice-versa/727859?noredirect=1#comment1379983_727855). However, if you really want to be able to do this you could put both users into the same group and ensure that files are created with group write permissions.

Preparation:

```
# Add shared working group
groupadd bothusers
usermod -aG bothusers usera
usermod -aG bothusers userb

# Increase write permissions to both users' directory trees
find ~usera/* ~userb/* -exec chmod g=u {} +

# Set group membership
find ~usera/* ~userb/* -exec chgrp bothusers {} +
```

You may want to reduce the `*` wildcard in the two `find` commands to match only the appropriate directory tree(s).

Invoke this at the beginning of each and every session (maybe in `~/.bashrc` or in your configuration setup scripts):

```
# Create files with group write permissions
umask 0002
```

You may find it useful to run per-user variants of both `find` commands  either hourly from `cron` or at the point of logging in.

Note that this does not change the users' primary group to `bothusers`. You can use `newgrp bothusers` to do that for the current session - but be aware it will start a new subshell.

Comment: Ah. When you said "full access" I assumed you wanted to switch between users. It sounds like you want to be able to write in each other's directory tree. That's not a great idea but you could do it with shared group access

Comment: @Black there you go, and alternate solution with file permissions